# How to add html bold tag to an embedded html code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble putting bold tags on just a few items in my code. It will bold the entire words including the added variable. (I don't want the variable to be bolded). Thanks!

```
"<p>" + " Given the severity of the change listed below, you are being asked to review and either approve or reject this change. Submitted by: "  + row.requester
+ "<p>" + "<b>Description: </b>" + row.commentsAndGeneralDescriptionOfTheChangeBeingImplementedAndAnySpecialInstructions
+ "<p>" + "<b>Report Id: </b>" + row.rowNumber
```

Here is some additional context for the snippet above:

```
function sendReportToManager(row) { 
    var message = "<HTML><BODY>" + "<p>" +" Given the severity of the change listed below, you are being asked to review and either approve or reject this change. Submitted by: " + row.requester + 
    "<p>" + "<b>Description: </b>" + row.commentsAndGeneralDescriptionOfTheChangeBeingImplementedAndAnySpecialInstructions + 
    "<p>" + "<b>Report Id: </b> " + row.rowNumber + 
    '<p><b>Please approve or reject <A HREF="' + APPROVAL_FORM_URL + '">Change Request</A> #' + row.rowNumber + "</HTML></BODY>";
     MailApp.sendEmail(row.changeManagerApproval, "Change Management Approval - REQUEST", "", {noReply: true, htmlBody: message}); 
}
```

Comment: the *items in your code* are what exactly?

Comment: You've posted a string, with no indication as to how/where you're *using* that string.

Comment: Most likely an unterminated `<b>` in one of your variables.

Comment: even the "Given the severity of the change listed below.." ?

Comment: the items that have the + are the variables and they are being bolded even though I ended the bold tag. So for example in Description: everything is bolded and I only want the word Description: to be bolded.

Comment: function sendReportToManager(row) {
var message = "<HTML><BODY>" + "<p>" +" Given the severity of the change listed below, you are being asked to review and either approve or reject this change. Submitted by: "  + row.requester
+ "<p>" + "<b>Description: </b>"  + row."above code"
    + "<p>" + "<b>Report Id: </b> " + row.rowNumber
    + '<p><b>Please approve or reject   <A HREF="' + APPROVAL_FORM_URL + '">Change Request</A> #' + row.rowNumber
    + "</HTML></BODY>";
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.changeManagerApproval, "Change Management Approval - REQUEST", "", {noReply: true, htmlBody: message});
}

Comment: @Tim There is definitely some context missing here. Either you have a `<b>` tag that occurs before this string, or the content of one or more of your variables contains a `<b>`. When you inspect the source, what do you see in the markup?

Comment: This is my code not sure why the format went away though.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrRWdR

Comment: where is the terminating bold tag for this?  `<b>Please approve or reject` ?

Comment: Thats weird that it works for you I have this code being sent by email. Do you think gmail is rejecting the end bold??? Because it will change it to bold it just wont end the bold.

Comment: what is being returned by the variable `commentsAndGeneralDescriptionOfTheChangeBeingImplementedAndAnySpecialInstructions`?

Comment: Its just a cell in a google sheet (so just some text). Thats the name of the description... I know its long and annoying but I only had to type it once. lol.

Comment: well.. I would try to replace the *<b>* for *<strong>*

Comment: OK thanks ill do that and let you know what happens.

Comment: Your a genius!!!!! It worked!!! Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrRWdR)

Your example works.  The question you have (why is the bold is not terminating) cannot be determined by the information you have given.  If your variables (e.g.`row.requester`) has an open `<strong>` or `<b>`, it would apply to the HTML until its closing tag is encountered.

A better way to do what you desire is to use CSS and better HTML tags, if your mail client accepts it.  For example:

```
"<p>" 
   + "Given the severity of the change listed below, you are being asked to review and either approve or reject this change. "
   + '<span class="label">Submitted by: </span><span class="value">'  
   + row.requester
+ "<p>" 
   + '<span class="label">Description: </span><span class="value">' 
   + row.commentsAndGeneralDescriptionOfTheChangeBeingImplementedAndAnySpecialInstructions
   + "</span>"
+ "<p>" 
   + '<span class="label">Report Id: </span><span class="value">' 
   + row.rowNumber
   + "</span>"
```

And then add some CSS:

```
.label { font-weight: bold; }
.value { font-weight: normal; }
```

---

***Note:** There are other issues with embedding HTML tags in a string, as you have done above - this answer does not address those concerns.  Instead, this answer should be used as a first step into solving the issue in the question asked.*

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you got some extra stuff you dont need in there. Try this:

```
"<strong>Given the severity of the change listed below, you are being asked to review and either approve or reject this change.</strong>" + \n  +
"<strong>Submitted by:</strong> " + row.requester +  \n +
"<strong>Description: </strong> "+ row.commentsAndGeneralDescriptionOfTheChangeBeingImplementedAndAnySpecialInstructions +  \n +
"<strong>Report Id:</strong> " + row.rowNumber
```

Comment: how does this bold anything?

Comment: Lines are broken for readability. Otherwise the script runs off the screen.
It has no impact on the usability of the script, and it fixes his/her issue

That said, yes you can insert new lines in a string literal using the \n (newline) escape char in JS.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my response (use an escape char).

Comment: OK, you fixed the syntax errors. Still, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I never had any syntax errors. I explained what to do in my answer. OP changed the format of his question after I answered. I updated my answer to match his revised question.